# When I enter FALSE...I receive the false output and when I put TRUE..i receive the true output but when enter NO ..I still receive the True Output

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, dapps, web3.py

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract booleans {

```
bool private isActive;

function hashSalt(bool _isActive) public returns (string memory) {
    isActive = _isActive;
    if (isActive) {
        return "SALT";
    }

    return "The state is not in active mode";
}
```

}

Comment: In some languages, just not being false, null or zero means that the bool is true. Apparently solidity treats anything non empty as true. By what I recember, in solidity even 0 is treated as true, and there is no null in solidity, so I think that only false is false, otherwise anything is true. That is my guess.

Comment: doesn't that create a potential security issue?? @JoãoPauloMorais

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you modify your question? What do you mean when I put NO.

Booleans can take only 2 values. True and False if you try to pass it anything else it won't work.

Comment: "In some languages, just not being false, null or zero means that the bool is true. Apparently solidity treats anything non empty as true. By what I recember, in solidity even 0 is treated as true, and there is no null in solidity, so I think that only false is false, otherwise anything is true. That is my guess." courtesy of @JoãoPauloMorais